# jquery Hover - Fade Image to Another

Tags: jquery, image, hover, fade

There have been multiple questions regarding this topic but I have never really settled on a solid answer.  I have also tried various different ways and never found really the best solution.

In my situation, I have a bunch of flags I need to place in the header of my page.  Each flag is a PNG, and I have also rendered out black and white versions of them.  I want to add a simple CSS class to (either a DIV or an IMG, or something!) and have a small peice of jquery that will fade to the color image when I hover over it, and fade out when I am not hovering over it.

I dont want to do it with CSS because thats boring.  Jquery is the way forward I feel, and it will look alot more classy.

Please help, I want the smallest most efficient code possible, without layers upon layers of CSS or a huge .JS include file.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  var x=0;
  $("#usa_d").hover(function() {
   $("#usa_d").fadeOut(400);
   x = 1;   
   //$("#usa_d").fadeOut(400,function(){$(this).attr('src',$('#usa_n').attr('src')).fadeIn();});
   $('#t').html('ON');
   
   ///alert('hover');
  });
  $("#usa_d").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(900);
    $('#t').html('off');
   //alert('focusout');
   //$("#usa_n").fadeOut(400,function(){$(this).attr('src',$('#usa_d').attr('src')).fadeIn();});
  });
 }); But this isnt working.  Sorry for the terrible formatting I am quite new to stackOverflow

Comment: However, that seems to work fine except that - I cant it see it working well with more than one image, and, it seems to like to fade in and out again when I stop hovering.  And I cant work out why.  The HTML there was an attempt to debug that.

Comment: Wow, if you want to post some code, use the edit function and update your question, this is unreadable. Or make an example fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Aah right sorry about that. :P I couldn't see how to do anything but comment lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this maybe:

```
<div class="flag" style="background-image:url(bw.png)"><img src="incolor.png" style="display:none;"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flag').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().fadeIn('fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this is working very well.  I'll need to mod it a bit of course to work but It's exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much!

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` will animate dimensions as well, which I don't think you want.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Arnar Yngvason may exhibit a problem if you quickly move the mouse in and out of the image multiple times. This can lead to an animation freeze. This flaw can be circumvented by using the fadeTo method instead of the fadeIn/fadeOut methods:

```
<div class="flag" style="background-image:url(bw.png)"><img src="incolor.png" style="display:none;"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flag').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo(400, 1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo(400, 0);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class"flag-area england"><div>
<div class"flag-area germany"><div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Example default values */
.flag-area
{
    background-position: 5px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Flag specfic values */
.flag-area.england
{
    background-image:url('images/england.png')
}

/* Flag specfic values */
.colored-flag.england
{
    background-image:url('images/england_colored.png')
}

.colored-flag.germany
{
    background-image:url('images/germany_colored.png')
}
```

JavaSript:

```
$('.flag-area').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('colored-flag', 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('colored-flag', 1000 );
});
```

But if you can solve this problem using CSS and use rules like, I recommend do avoid javascript:

```
/* Flag specfic values */
.flag-area.england:hover
{
    background-image:url('images/england_colored.png')
}
```

And another hint: if you have a lot of flags to display, dont't use many images but only one with containing all flags and instead of changing background-image, use for all flags the same background-image and change its position.

Comment: Wont this just act exactly like a CSS Hover? There is no fading, surley?

Comment: And Yes that is a good idea to have an 'iconset' as it were - but what are the real advantages of this - is it simply just faster? I see it alot on the huge sites like twitter and facebook when looking at their sources.

Comment: Well you only have to do one call for the iconset image and avoid to produce to much traffic. Every GET prevented is a good GET :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/efovuz/2/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .flag { width:350px; height:150px; position:relative; }
  .flag img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flag">  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0" /> 
  <img class="bw" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/" />  
</div>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('.flag').hover(
          function () {
              $(this).children('.bw').first().fadeOut('slow');
           },
          function () {
              $(this).children('.bw').first().fadeIn('slow');
           }
        ); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why? positioning is a rock solid way of laying things out and controlling things if you understand it and use it as its meant to be.